# Does Redstorm support multiple streams

Tags: ruby, apache-storm

Storm support multiple streams, but i cannot found relative dsl in Redstorm, any knowns if it's supported or not, and how to use it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The DSL does not currently provide a mechanism to specify different streams, but you can do it with the TopologyBuilder class.

```
java_import 'backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder'

topology_builder = TopologyBuilder.new(...)
...
topology_builder.setBolt(...).shuffleGrouping('source', 'stream')
```